# Index optimization when range is known in advance

Tags: oracle, indexing, range

I am creating a table which has a column for week number. A number of queries run with week number in where clause. So we are creating an index on this column. But as there are only 53 weeks in a year (52 or 53), I wanted to check if there is any way that I can provide this range for the column/index and will it improve the performance in any way? I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Consider partitioned table using a week number as a key, instead of the index on week numbers, partitioning can give much better performance.

Comment: What is the volume of the table. It would be good if you could benchmark the performance after creating the index on production like volumes and ascertain whether they are satisfactory. If your table size is above 1 GB then it makes sense partitioning it based on your week key.

Comment: Really, the question kind of comes down to data distribution.  At this point, there are 53 distinct values (assuming that every year restarts with week 1 or 0).  As rows are entered, the value of the index on that column becomes much less useful.  If there are thousands, or millions, of rows inserted daily for a given week, without partitioning, the index becomes relatively weak.  If the partition key is only on week, as years go by the index will also become weaker.  Can you give us more information?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle automatically determines most of the relevant information about your objects when it gathers optimizer statistics.  It collects the number of rows, number of distinct values, low and high value, etc.  That information can be viewed in `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.  Oracle uses that information to pick the fastest query plans, and it is almost always good enough.

By default, optimizer statistics are gathered once a day for objects that are new or had significant data changes.  If necessary, optimizer statistics can be manually gathered like this:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('USER_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME');
end;
/
```

Comment: Deprecated since at least 10Gr1. `Do not use the COMPUTE and ESTIMATE clauses of ANALYZE to collect optimizer statistics` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_4005.htm See DBMS_STATS instead, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#CIHBIEII (Though find the version specific of help to match the version of Oracle you are running.)